# Поиск похожих записей через форму в MS Access

Tags: sql, база-данных, access, vba, ms-access

Добрый день. Есть таблица в MS Access, в которой присутствует числовое поле "номинал", при чем записей с одинаковым номиналом может быть больше одной. Необходимо создать форму, на которой должны быть два поля. В одном поле отображается список записей этой таблицы. При клике на запись, в другом поле должны отображаться записи с таким же номиналом, как у выделенной записи. Прошу помощи, не могу придумать, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: вам SQL запрос нужен который выбирает поля с указанным номиналом?

Comment: Сам запрос я и сам могу написать, благодарю. Я не понимаю, как можно сделать выборку нужных мне записей именно через форму

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в форме сделаль 2 подформы. Одна содержит ваши записи, а другая, содержит те-же записи, но с фильтром по выделенному значению номинала из первой формы.